# How to use IN operator with temporary tables

Tags: mysql

I have "puri" and "mailraku" as two temporary tables. How to fix this query? The documentation about "IN" doesn't mention it.

```
UPDATE tr_lines_alls
SET ACT_FLG = 0
WHERE IMG_ID IN (puri, mailraku);
```

The error says:

```
 Unknown column 'puri' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: what's the table structure of puri and mailraku? IN needs a set of values or a subquery

Comment: what do you wish to with your query? Do you want to update a column on condition that img_id in table to update matches with img_id in puri and mailraku table??

Comment: I want to update ACT_FLG of tr_lines_alls table which has IMG_ID in a set. That set includes two temporary tables. The temp tables has only one colum IMG_ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IN` operator is not for tables, but for lists of values!!
Maybe you need something as:

```
UPDATE tr_lines_alls
SET ACT_FLG = 0
WHERE IMG_ID IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
        (SELECT yourcolumn FROM puri) UNION 
        (SELECT yourcolumn FROM mailraku)
    ) AS tmp_union
);
```

Comment: I tried your solution:
UPDATE tr_lines_alls
SET ACT_FLG = 0
WHERE IMG_ID IN ( (SELECT IMG_ID FROM puri) UNION (SELECT IMG_ID FROM mailraku) );
-- Error syntax near "UNION (SELECT IMG_ID FROM mailraku) );"

Comment: It seems that the `UNION` query must be wrapper in a single-table expression. I updated the answer. Try it now.

Comment: I tried this:
UPDATE tr_lines_alls
SET ACT_FLG = 0
WHERE IMG_ID IN 
(SELECT IMG_ID FROM 
 (SELECT IMG_ID FROM puri) UNION (SELECT IMG_ID FROM mailraku) AS temp
);

-- Error "#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: You did a mistake copying my code. Pay attention to parenthesis!

Answer (score -1):

Do you want something like this? IN operator won't take temporary columns only values or column names. 
If you want to update your table on condition that  img_id in table to update matches with img_id in puri and mailraku table, then u can try this:

```
UPDATE tr_lines_alls
SET ACT_FLG = 0
WHERE tr_lines_alls.IMG_ID = puri.IMG_ID and tr_lines_alls.IMG_ID = mailkaru.IMG_ID
```

Comment: That code will not work because `puri` and `mailkaru` tables have not been loaded with any statement. Additionally, if you load these tables and use that query, you will update row that have `IMG_ID` matching with both tables, that I think it's not what the user want.

Comment: yes, then my answer is incorrect. But my poor 2 points.    ;)